# url change without anchor tag and refresh using ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, url

As per my client need , redirect the page without anchor tag and refresh page ,
 and change the URL as per page appearance. I don't know any idea about this. 
I can use ajax for page content. but I don't know the URL change option without 
page refresh or redirect. how can I do this with ajax j-query. Any one guide me for this issue.thanks advance

sample url

`www.samplesite.com/contact.php` -> without anchor tag. and page refresh this url need to work on php.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for info about the new HTML5 History API ( pushstate ), this link has a detailed tutorial.

http://diveintohtml5.info/history.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following javascript functions

```js
window.location.assign('http://www.samplesite.com/contact.php'); // keeps the current page in browser history

window.location.replace('http://www.samplesite.com/contact.php'); // replaces the current page in browser history

window.location = 'http://www.samplesite.com/contact.php'; // the same as assign() and is backward compatible even with the oldest browsers
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NcB2w/4/show/)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using below function.

```
if(pageurl!=window.location){
  window.history.pushState({path:pageurl},'',pageurl);
}
```